# how to find out which class the UICollectionViewCell class is in?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionviewcell

I'm having a little trouble here.  I'm using a `UICollectionViewCell` class in 2 different `UIViewController` classes, how can I find which of the `UIViewController` class in the `UICollectionViewCell` class in from the `UICollectionViewCell` class?  The `UICollectionViewCell` has some button properties, and I would like to change the color of the buttons depending on the `UIViewController`.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea, as it increases coupling in your code severely. If different controllers require different colors, seems to me better to expose an interface to do that on your cell.

Comment: You should always put the color changing code in the view controller. Not in the cell.